# NixOS QEMU VM does not appear in `virsh` on Debian

Tags: qemu, nix, virsh

I am running the Nix package manager on a Debian system.

On this Debian system, I use Nix to start a QEMU VM running NixOS, following this tutorial: https://github.com/pdtpartners/nix-snapshotter#getting-started

This successfully starts a QEMU VM running NixOS:

```
$ ps -ef | grep qemu-kvm
peterbe+ 1188452 1147771 99 12:40 pts/1    00:00:35 
  /nix/store/g7xr4cd1j34hkmf4sdf64baxanfsbpin-qemu-host-cpu-only-8.0.2/bin/qemu-kvm 
    -cpu max -name nixos -m 4096 ......
```

The Nix package manager provides the `qemu-kvm` binary. Debian provides the `virsh` binary:

```
$ which virsh
/usr/bin/virsh
```

Should this QEMU VM be listed by `virsh`?

```
$ virsh list --all      
 Id   Name   State
--------------------
```

I'm guessing it fails because I am not using the Debian-provided QEMU, and Debian-provided `virsh` doesn't know about Nix-provided QEMU.

Comment: You are confusing QEMU: https://www.qemu.org/ with libvirt: https://libvirt.org/